# Git Workflow for a new empty Branch

Tags: git, branch

I have a master branch with a Vue project. Now I decided to use Quasar as a CSS Framework and therefore I need a new setup/project. I want to use the same Git Repo so my Question is if there is a best practice workflow for something like this?
So actually I need a new empty branch which should be later on the new master as soon as the Quasar Project is at the same level as the master.

Comment: Note: there is no such thing as an *empty* branch. When you create a new branch, that new branch contains many commits—the same ones as some other branch. What happens *after* that matters: when you add new commits to the new branch, the new branch advances, and now it contains the old commits plus the new ones.

Comment: Oke thanks, so in the end I have to delete all the files in the new created quasar branch and afterwards setup a new Project with the quasar CLI?

Comment: I know nothing of your build system, but you *can* store multiple projects in a single repository (a "monorepo"). If the project are totally independent, though, it's usually wiser to use multiple repositories. If you do go with a monorepo, you rarely want to *delete* a project from some branch, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your main branch is `master`. If not, change the commands below to the correct branch name.

Create a new work branch:

```
git checkout -b quasar master
```

Then, modify your code (adding commits etc) and once it works, merge it back:

```
git checkout master
git merge quasar
```

If you don't change `master` while developing on `quasar`, this should work without problems. Otherwise, you might have to resolve conflicts if you modify some code in different ways on the two branches.